# Named Semaphore with async calls

Tags: c#, async-await

I have multiple distinct processes that need to access external resources that are rate limited.  The processes are all async in nature and run in different applications.  In times past I would just use SemaphoreSlim this design doesn't allow for that.

I've found several samples that seem to be half complete, or cut and paste into their code.  This was derived from an existing post, but heavily modified to encompass the additional methods and to honor the cancellation token.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
public sealed class SemaphoreAsync : IDisposable
{
  Semaphore _semaphore;

  private SemaphoreAsync(Semaphore sem) => _semaphore = sem;
  public SemaphoreAsync(int initialCount, int maximumCount) => _semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount, maximumCount);
  public SemaphoreAsync(int initialCount, int maximumCount, string name) => _semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount, maximumCount, name);
  public SemaphoreAsync(int initialCount, int maximumCount, string name, out bool createdNew, SemaphoreSecurity semaphoreSecurity) => _semaphore = new Semaphore(initialCount, maximumCount, name, out createdNew, semaphoreSecurity);

  public static SemaphoreAsync OpenExisting(string name)
  {
    return new SemaphoreAsync(Semaphore.OpenExisting(name));
  }

  public static SemaphoreAsync OpenExisting(string name, SemaphoreRights rights)
  {
    return new SemaphoreAsync(Semaphore.OpenExisting(name, rights));
  }

  public static bool TryOpenExisting(string name, out SemaphoreAsync result)
  {
    if (Semaphore.TryOpenExisting(name, out Semaphore semaphore))
    {
      result = new SemaphoreAsync(semaphore);
      return true;
    }
    result = null;
    return false;
  }

  public static bool TryOpenExisting(string name, SemaphoreRights rights, out SemaphoreAsync result)
  {
    if (Semaphore.TryOpenExisting(name, rights, out Semaphore semaphore))
    {
      result = new SemaphoreAsync(semaphore);
      return true;
    }
    result = null;
    return false;
  }

  public async Task<bool> WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken ct)
  {
    DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while (!_semaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      if (DateTime.UtcNow < start.Add(timeout))
        return false;
      await Task.Delay(100, ct);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public async Task<bool> WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken ct)
  {
    DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while (!_semaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      if (millisecondsTimeout > 0)
      {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow < start.AddMilliseconds(millisecondsTimeout))
          return false;
      }
      await Task.Delay(100, ct);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public async Task<bool> WaitOne(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    while (!_semaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      await Task.Delay(100, ct);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public SemaphoreSecurity GetAccessControl()
  {
    return _semaphore.GetAccessControl();
  }

  public int Release()
  {
    return _semaphore.Release();
  }

  public int Release(int releaseCount)
  {
    return _semaphore.Release(releaseCount);
  }

  public void SetAccessControl(SemaphoreSecurity semaphoreSecurity)
  {
    _semaphore.SetAccessControl(semaphoreSecurity);
  }


  #region IDisposable Support
  private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls
  void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        if (_semaphore != null)
        {
          _semaphore.Dispose();
          _semaphore = null;
        }
      }
      disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
  public void Dispose()
  {
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    Dispose(true);
  }
  #endregion

}
```

Comment: You could simply use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store `SemaphoreSlim`s.
`SemaphoreSlim` already supports async operations.

Comment: The challenge is that SemaphoreSlim is limited to only a single application, we're specifically looking for async locking wrapper for the Semaphore class across multiple applications using a named semaphore (which SemaphoreSlim can't do).

Comment: @GarySmith I know this is old, but can you please share what you ended up doing?  I'm in a similar situation at the moment.

Comment: @LorneCash see my answer inline.  I use a similar class to what I posted for both C# and python.  So if you create two instances of C# one will win and the other will lose.  If you create a C# and python, one will win and the other will lose.  It solved my case at the time.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject?view=netframework-4.7.1) to register a callback when a the `WaitHandle` (`Semaphore` extends `WaitHandle`) is signaled.

Together with a `TaskCompletionSource` you could completely remove all your wait loops.

Example:

```
private async Task Run()
{
    var semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 1);
    await AwaitWaitHandle(semaphore, CancellationToken.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
}

private Task AwaitWaitHandle(WaitHandle handle, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var reg = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(handle,
        (state, timedOut) =>
        {
            // Handle timeout
            if (timedOut)
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();

            taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }, null, timeout, true);

    // Handle cancellation
    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        reg.Unregister(handle);
        taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
    });

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

You could use `AwaitWaitHandle` in your `SemaphoreAsync` implementation to await the Semaphore.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  I'm going to try this and the other method presented here.  At first I thought there would be issues with multiple calls on the same CancellationToken but I noticed that you're unregistered it on the actual event.

Comment: The `Unregister` should probably be given `null` parameter (we do not want ot signal anything upon cancellation). The `CancellationTokenRegistration` should be probably disposed on successful wait.

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` can be replaced with `Timeout.Infinite`. `CancellationToken.None` can be replaced with `default`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could rewrite the wait operations to await both the semaphore or cancellation token.

> ```
> public async Task<bool> WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken ct)
>   {
>     DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
>     while (!_semaphore.WaitOne(0))
>     {
>       ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
>       if (DateTime.UtcNow < start.Add(timeout))
>         return false;
>       await Task.Delay(100, ct);
>     }
>     return true;
>   }
> ```

```
  public async Task<bool> WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken ct)
  {
      var success = await Task.Run(() =>
      {
          return WaitHandle.WaitTimeout
              != WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _semaphore, ct.WaitHandle }, timeout);
      });
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      return success;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going in a different direction.  The secondary application that we needed to synchronize ended up being in python.  The below code works for c# self-locking as well as python in the mix.  It was taken from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c for the C# portion.

C#:

```
namespace SandBox
{
    using System.Security.AccessControl;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        static log4net.ILog _log;

        static Mutex mutex;
        static bool mutexCreated;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mutexId = $"test1";
            MutexAccessRule allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(
               new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
               MutexRights.FullControl,
               AccessControlType.Allow);
            MutexSecurity securitySettings = new MutexSecurity();
            securitySettings.AddAccessRule(allowEveryoneRule);

            // initiallyOwned: true == false + mutex.WaitOne()
            mutex = new Mutex(initiallyOwned: true, mutexId, out mutexCreated, securitySettings);

            if (!mutexCreated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Already started!");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("wait");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }

            if (mutexCreated)
            {
                try
                {
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                catch (ApplicationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception throw on mutexrelease!");
                }
            }
            mutex.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Python:

```
import os
import time

class mutext_test(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        if self.isWin():
            self.ensure_win32api()
            self.mutexname = id
            self.lock = win32event.CreateMutex(None, False, self.mutexname)
            self.running = (win32api.GetLastError() == winerror.ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

        else:
            self.ensure_fcntl()
            self.lock = open(f"/tmp/instance_{id}.lock", 'wb')
            try:
                fcntl.lockf(self.lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                self.running = False
            except IOError:
                self.running = True

    def already_running(self):
        return self.running
    
    def __del__(self):
        if self.lock:
            try:
                if self.isWin():
                    win32api.CloseHandle(self.lock)
                else:
                    os.close(self.lock)
            except Exception as ex:
                pass

    # ---------------------------------------
    # Utility Functions
    # Dynamically load win32api on demand
    # Install with: pip install pywin32
    win32api=winerror=win32event=None
    def ensure_win32api(self):
        global win32api,winerror,win32event
        if self.win32api is None:
            import win32api
            import winerror
            import win32event


    # Dynamically load fcntl on demand
    # Install with: pip install fcntl
    fcntl=None
    def ensure_fcntl(self):
        global fcntl
        if self.fcntl is None:
            import fcntl

    def isWin(self):
        return (os.name == 'nt')
    # ---------------------------------------

sic = mutext_test("test1")
if sic.already_running():
    print("An instance of {} is already running.".format("test1"))
    sys.exit(1)

while (True):
    print("wait")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: If you want your alternate approach reviewed, you should post a follow up question with a link back to this question, That might be better than posting your own answer.

Comment: It was more or less for the person who was asking what my solution was.  But I see your point.